# What is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4^{n} r^{n\beta} e^{n} t^{n-1}}{ e^{(4r^{\beta} (n-1)+1) t}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\beta, r>0.$
Define

$$F(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4^{n} r^{n\beta} e^{n} t^{n-1}}{ e^{(4r^{\beta} (n-1)+1) t}},\quad  0<t<T$$

My question is:

> Can we say that $\|F\|_{L^{\infty}[0, T]} = \infty$ if $T\geq \frac{1}{4r^{\beta}}$

Edit: $F(t)=\frac{e^{4r^{\beta}t}}{e^{t}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(4r^{\beta}e t^{-1})^n}{(e^{4r^{\beta}t})^n}= \frac{e^{4r^{\beta}t}}{e^{t}} \frac{e^{4r^{\beta}t}}{e^{4r^{\beta}t}- 4r^{\beta} e t^{-1}}$ I think, I'm missing something to sum the series. Kindly correct me.

Comment: You can sum the series  explicitly since it is essentially  a geometric series. As far as I can see $F$ is bounded on $[0,T]$ for  every $T$.

Comment: Thanks. Is this $F(t)=\frac{e^{4r^{\beta}t}}{e^{t}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(4r^{\beta}e t^{-1})^n}{(e^{4r^{\beta}t})^n}= \frac{e^{4r^{\beta}t}}{e^{t}} \frac{e^{4r^{\beta}t}}{e^{4r^{\beta}t}- 4r^{\beta} e t^{-1}}$ correct? I' think I'm missing something...

Comment: @Murphy: If this sum is correct, please would explain why it will be remain bounded? Thanks.

Comment: I think you are writing $t^{n-1}$ as $(t^{-1})^{n}$ which is incorrect. Once this is corrected use the inequality$ e^{x} >1+x$ for  all $x >0$ to see that $F$ is bounded.